# How to break a paragraph between double {}

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

**Document class**

I use the following document class: sig-alternate.cls

The document class can be found at: http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates

**Problem:**

I have the following code:

```
\conferenceinfo{Text 1 here}{Text 2 here}
```

and I wish the output would be:

```
Text 1 here
Text 2 here
```

Right now both text sentences align after each other.

I have tried to look at double \ and also at \newline but haven't been successful so far.

Comment: It would help those trying to help you if you provided an MWE starting with `\documentclass` and demonstrating the issue.

Comment: '\newcommand\conferenceinfo[2]{\noindent#1\par\noindent#2}`? (I'm assuming you don't want to indent the first argument.)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sorry about that, I will update the description.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I tried your suggestion but both text sentences disappeared. I have updated the problem description that I use the ACM template.

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example, including a `\documentclass` command and a `document` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to insert a paragraph break, but the usual `\par` command will not work here.  Rather you need to use `\endgraf`:

[image: Sample output snippet]

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\begin{document}
\conferenceinfo{Text 1 here}{\endgraf Text 2 here.\endgraf More.}

\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The `\conferenceinfo` macro is defined in a way that does not allow paragraph breaks in its arguments; `\endgraf` is the replacement command available in such situations (a relic from plain TeX).

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work flawlessly:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\conferenceinfo{Text 1 here}{\\ Text 2 here.}

\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\maketitle

\section{A}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Magnified view

[image]